# View State issue on VF page

Tags: visualforce, viewstate

I have a VF page where i am displaying the records from a custom object using different SOQL search statement. But when the number of record is getting more i am getting an error of View State. Which mean that VF page cannot hold that much records. How can i resolve it? Please guide me a best way to get this issue resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view state is primarily a serialised version of a) the non-transient fields of the controller class and b) the page component tree built by the Visualforce `apex:` tags.

You should find out which of these the problem is with starting from the "Examining the View State" section of [An Introduction to Visualforce View State](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State). That article also includes the common approaches to addressing the problem.

Also click on the [viewstate tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewstate) here and browse the various postings on the subject.

The fix might be very simple e.g. instead of assigning your search results to a field just return them from a getter method.

Comment: +1 for returning from getter method. It's often unnecessary to actually store the data in view state if it's read only. Even if it's writable, you can usually use a getter and setter together to get the desired effect without much trouble.